# Can flexbox be used to 'sticky' the last footer section by expanding the previous footer section?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, sticky-footer

Given the basic HTML structure (which I can't change) below, I know I can expand the main content div with this CSS:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#columns {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

.footer {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    HEADER CONTENT
  </header>
  <div id="columns" class="container">
    MAIN CONTENT
  </div>
  <footer class="footer">
    <div class="container"> </div>
    <div id="footer-content">
      FOOTER CONTENT
   </div>
  </footer>
</body>
```

But the 'columns' section has styling that I don't really want extending below the content, so I would prefer, if possible, to expand the penultimate *empty* div (.container) within the footer section.

I've tried everything I can think of, but I'm a css beginner and nothing has worked.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out using [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LXVxmX) in SCSS mode so I could nest selectors. That made experimenting a whole lot easier.

It turned out I needed two flexboxes: one to expand the whole footer section to fill the available space, and one *within* the footer to expand the padding container likewise.

Here's the code with `background-color` added to each content section for illustration purposes:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0;
}
body header {
  background-color: green;
}
body #columns {
  background-color: blue;
}
body #footer-content {
  background-color: red;
}
body .footer {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
body .footer .container {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    HEADER CONTENT
  </header>
  <div id="columns" class="container">
    MAIN CONTENT
  </div>
  <footer class="footer">
    <div class="container"> </div>
    <div id="footer-content">
      FOOTER CONTENT
   </div>
  </footer>
</body>
```